# AVPlayer will not stop playing when going back to the previous view controller (SWIFT)

Tags: swift

I have two View Controllers a TableViewController where i have a list of musics and a UIViewController where it displays the music details and plays the music. The music automatically plays when the view is loaded and pauses when the pause button is pressed. However whenever I go back to the previous TableViewController to select another music, the music continues to play. And if i select another music, both of them are playing together

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timeLabel.text = "00:00"

    if let object = currentObject {

        audioTitle.text = object["audioTitle"] as? String
        let days = object["daysActive"] as! Int
        daysActive.text = "Powertalks: Day \(days)"

        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "trc_app_icon.png")

        audioImage.image = initialThumbnail
        if let thumbnail = object["image"] as? PFFile {
            audioImage.file = thumbnail
            audioImage.loadInBackground()
        }

        if let audioFile = object["audioFile"] as? PFFile {

            if let audioPath: String = audioFile.url {

            audioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: audioPath))

            audioSlider.minimumValue = 0
            audioSlider.maximumValue = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration))
            audioSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(audioPlayer.currentTime()))

            audioPlayer.volume = volumeSlider.value

            playAudio()

            }

        }

    }

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateSlider"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true )

}
```

Comment: could you fix your problem anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pause the player when the view disappears. Although `AVPlayer` doesn't have a stop method, you can set the `rate` to `0.0` (or use `pause()`) and set `currentItem` to nil to achieve the same effect. Try using the below code (not tested)

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
   audioPlayer.pause()
   audioPlayer.currentItem = nil
 }
```

Comment: AVPlayer is not member of UIKit , he has own layout .

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'currentItem' is a get-only property

Comment: @Penkey Suresh, I have a AVPlayer in a subview of UIView and I had nil that super view but still that view are not removing from superview when I pop the main view controller. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Hello @Penkey Suresh my problem is when i am go to previous view controller song play stop ,So how to play song .

Answer (score -2):

I tested the code below which works fine:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
audioPlayer.pause()
audioPlayer.currentItem = nil
}
```

You could also use:
    audioPlayer.stop()